# Automatically Turn Cell Into Formulas in Numbers

Tags: numbers

I'd like to know if it's possible to automatically turn a column of cell data into individual functions. Here is an example what I'm working with. Instead of having to edit each dark grey cell individually and append an "=" at the beginning, I want to select all in that column so that they can represent the data in the provided cell coordinates.

Thanks!

[image: Sample]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can individually get the values stored in the cells pointed by the contents of the cells in the dark grey column in your post easily using the INDIRECT() function in Numbers.

It is an easy to use function but below is an example for your convenience. In this example, the value of 241 stored in cell B2 is pulled into cell D4 using the INDIRECT() function which utilizes the content of cell C4, "B2", as its argument.

[image]